# Android Save and retrieve Jpeg files using Base64

Tags: base64

i use below code to get .jpeg files content as Base64 and send it to web service.

```
    public static String GetBase64File(String filepath)
{
    String ret="";
    byte[] bytes = null;
    try {
        bytes = readFile(filepath);         
    } catch (IOException e) {           
    }
    try {ret=Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);}catch (Exception e) {}
    return ret;
}
```

and then , i use this code for save retrieved content from web service as .jpeg file:

```
    public static String SaveRetrievedAttachment(String data,String filename)
{
    Writer writer = null;       
    filename=Global.AppStorageTempsDir+UUID.randomUUID().toString().replaceAll("-", "")+getFileExtension(filename);
    byte[] AsBytes = Base64.decode(data.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);        
    String outs=new String(AsBytes);
    File outputFile = new File(filename);
    try {
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile));
    } catch (IOException e) {}
    try {
        writer.write(outs);
    } catch (IOException e) {}
    try {
        writer.close();         
    } catch (IOException e) {}
    return filename;
}
```

but my source .jpeg file is not equal retrieved .jpeg file.retrieved .jpeg file is not a known .jpeg format.
what is problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem on your saving method:

```
    byte[] AsBytes = Base64.decode(data.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);        
    String outs=new String(AsBytes);
    File outputFile = new File(filename);
    try {
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile));
    } catch (IOException e) {}
    try {
        writer.write(outs);
    } catch (IOException e) {}
    try {
        writer.close();         
    } catch (IOException e) {}
```

this is not correct, you can't save binary data into string (it will currpt the data), also you use character stream to save binary data.

you should save the bytes directly on  the file using FileOuputStream (Buffered or not), example:

```
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename));
bos.write(fileBytes);
bos.flush();
bos.close();
```